# Do eigenvalues mean something in roots equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $p(x)$ be a vector of polynomials up to $x^n$

$$p(x)=[1, \ x, \ \cdots, \ x^n]$$

Any polynomial of degree $n$ can be represented by the inner product of coefficients and $p$:

$$\mathbf{a}(x) = A^T \cdot p(x)$$
$$A = [\mathbf{a}_0, \ \mathbf{a}_1, \ \cdots, \ \mathbf{a}_n]^{T}$$

Which $A$ is a $(n \times m)$ matrix: $A_{i} = \mathbf{a}_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

My objective is find all the roots of $\mathbf{a}(x)$, which can be 0, finite or infinite.

Then instead of finding the root of each coordinate, my plan is find the root of $\langle \mathbf{a}(x), \mathbf{a}(x)\rangle$, which can be expressed as

$$p(x) \cdot M \cdot p(x) = 0$$
$$M_{ij} = \langle \mathbf{a}_i, \mathbf{a}_j\rangle$$
$$M = A \cdot A^T$$

$M$ is a real symmetric matrix

**Question:** What can be said about the roots of $\mathbf{a}(x)$ by using $M$? If none of the eigenvalues of $M$ are $0$, would it mean $\mathbf{a}(x)=\mathbf{0}$ has no solution?

**Motivation:**

I want to find if a bezier curve intersects the origin. The bezier functions are represented by

$$b_{i,n}(x) = \binom{n}{i}\left(1-x\right)^{n-i} \cdot x^i$$
$$b(x) = \left[b_{0,n}, \ b_{1,n}, \ \cdots, \ b_{n,n}\right]^T$$

It's possible to write a bezier curve $\mathbf{a}(x)$ by using $p(x)$:

$$\mathbf{a}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \mathbf{q}_{i} \cdot b_{i,n}(x) = Q^T \cdot b(x) = \underbrace{Q^T \cdot R}_{A} \cdot p(x) = A^T \cdot p(x)$$

Comment: did you try to think of an example? From what I understand, polynomial representation by inner product of coefficients and  is changing bases. So if you change the bases, you are not supposed to lose roots. but I don't understand why you would like to do such thing from the beginning.

Comment: @Jneven I added the motivation, which I think could serve as example. I don't try to use the inner product in polynomials like $\langle p(x), p(x) \rangle$, but only between points $\mathbb{a}$. I don't see why I would lose roots by transforming the coefficients. For example, finding the root $x_0$ by using $a(x) = A^T \cdot p(x)$ would be the same as finding the root by using $a(x) = Q^T \cdot b(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but (assuming that $A$ is a vector-column) your matrix $M$ writes
$$ M = AA^T,$$
and such matrices (unless $n=0$) always have a zero eigenvalue; it is sufficient to take any non-zero vector $B$ orthogonal to $A$ and check that $MB = AA^TB=0$.

I would say you need to find another characteristic of $M$ in order to deduce something about the roots of $a(x)$.

Comment: I think $M$ has always a zero eigenvalue if $m=1$, which would be the case for vector-column. But $A$ being a $(n\times m)$ matrix, it may not happen. Example: $A = [[1, 2], [3, 2]]$ gives $M=[[5, 7], [7, 13]]$, which has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \approx 0.93$ and $\lambda_2 \approx 17.06$

Comment: @CarlosAdir indeed; from the initial formulation of the question it was not 100% clear whether $A$ was a matrix or a vector. Anyway, whenever $m > n$ the matrix $M$ will have a zero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

In floating point arithmetic, your Bézier curve will hardly ever pass through the origin exactly.

So, the best you can do is find the minimum distance between the curve and the origin, and then check that this distance is acceptably small.

If your curve equation is given by a parametric equation $F(t)$, then the closest point to the origin corresponds to a parameter value $t=t_0$ that satisfies $F(t) \cdot F’(t) = 0$. So, finding $t_0$ is just a one-dimensional root-finding problem, which you can solve using your favorite numerical method.

If $F$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ (in any basis you like), then $F \cdot F’$ is a real-valued polynomial of degree $2n-1$, and you might get some benefit from using a root-finding method that’s specifically designed for polynomials.

Comment: Indeed, it's a good aproach used to compute projection of a point in a curve (from Nurbs' book). It leads us to find the value of $x$ such $\langle \mathbf{a}(x), \ \mathbf{a}'(x) \rangle = \sum_{i, j} p_i \dfrac{dp_j}{dx} \langle a_{i}, a_{j}\rangle = p(x) \cdot M \cdot p'(x) = 0$. This equation is in fact the derivative of $p(x) \cdot M(x) \cdot p(x) = 0$. While $p(x) \cdot M \cdot p(x) = 0$ does not always have a solution, $p(x) \cdot M \cdot p'(x) = 0$ often is more achiveable

Answer (score 0):

I came with this answer a few days after seeing the answers of bubba and TZakrevskiy

Since $M$ is a $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix, it has $(n+1)$ eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ related to eigenvectors $v_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such

$$M = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \lambda_i \cdot v_{i} \otimes v_{i}$$

As consequence

$$v_{i} \cdot M \cdot v_{i} = \lambda_i \ \ \ \ \forall i$$

Supposing the first $m$ eigenvalues of $M$ are zero, then any linear combination $r$ of the zero eigenvectors leads to

$$r \cdot M \cdot r = 0$$

$$r = \alpha_{0} \cdot v_0 + \cdots + \alpha_{m-1} \cdot v_{m-1}$$

The case of $p(x) \cdot M \cdot p(x) = 0$ only happens iif

$$p(x) = \alpha_0 \cdot v_0 + \cdots + \alpha_{m-1} \cdot v_{m-1}$$

Therefore,

- If $m = 0$ (there are $0$ eigenvalues), there is no solution
- If $m \ne 0$, then it may have solutions, only when $p(x)$ are linear combination of the eigenvectors.

Finding the best value of $x$ when $m\ne 0$ may be hard, and a numerical method may be required. But if the search is know if the system has a solution, finding the minimal eigenvalue of $M$ is enough. But for finding the best $x$, bubbas' solution is better by iterating on $M$